# How many possible permutations are there of a pacman board.

Tags: permutations

I am working on a Pacman RL project and need to validate that there are a correct number of state permutations that I generated. My logic is as follows:

There are 15 player positions, 15 ghost positions, 15 positions that can have/not have a pellet. A ghost and a player can occupy the same spot, and a player or a ghost can occupy a spot where there is a pellet. This would give
$$
15\cdot15\cdot2^{15}
$$

Would this be correct, if not why so? The code which I wrote to generate these permutations finds approximately 3.6 million possible permutations but my logic says there are approximately 7.3 million permutations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it matter that pacman cannot jump pellets? That is, pellets must be eaten in a sort of order?

Comment: I am trying to generate all permutations regardless if one is valid or not. Because this only needs to be done once I don’t care about complexity, and will then iterate over each state and validate which ones are possible.

Comment: Then your calculation is correct for $15$ positions for $1$ Pac-Man, $1$ ghost, and possible $15$ pellets.